# Mongoose (express, node, mongo) scope issue with findOne()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm having an issue with what I believe is the scope of a variable in mongoose.  My code is this:

```
var blogUserId;
blogs.forEach(function(blog, index) {
  User.findOne({'username': blog.username}, function(err, user) {
    blogUserId = user._id;
    console.log(blogUserId);
  });
  console.log(blogUserId);

  Blog.find({'title': blog.title}, function(err, blogs) {
    if (!err && !blogs.length) {
      console.log(blogUserId);
      Blog.create({title: blog.title, author: blogUserId, body: blog.body, hidden: blog.hidden});
    }
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

This is part of a seed file just for development, but I'm rather confused why it wouldn't be working.  `blogs` is just an array of objects to load into the collection.  I've searched on all similar answers but I haven't found a correct answer that would explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `blogUserId` is not set when your `Blog.find()` is called. You'd have to nest it differently, something like this:

```
var blogUserId;
blogs.forEach(function(blog, index) {
  User.findOne({'username': blog.username}, function(err, user) {
    blogUserId = user._id;
    console.log(blogUserId);

    Blog.find({'title': blog.title}, function(err, blogs) {
      if (!err && !blogs.length) {
        console.log(blogUserId);
        Blog.create({title: blog.title, author: blogUserId, body: blog.body, hidden: blog.hidden});
      }
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

  });

});
```

I haven't tested it so I'm not sure that there are no other errors in your code but was definitely a problem that you were calling `Blog.find` that expected the `blogUserId` to be set possibly before it was set in the `User.findOne` callback.

It can be written in a more readable way with named callbacks.

When working in Node you need to keep in mind that you are working in an asynchronous environment.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, that structure makes so much more sense anyway